# is python as capable as other languages like c++?

Tags: python

i am looking to start learning. people have told me it is juts as capable. though i haven't really seen any good looking games available. some decent ones on pygame, but none really stand out.

i would like to know if python really is as capable as other languages.

EDIT: thanks guys, is python good for game development?

Comment: Yes, C++ and Python are turing complete. so you can do (almost) everything in both languages.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Both languages can bind to C, so therefore they can as much as one another.

Comment: so how about for game development?

Answer (score 5):

Each language has strengths and weaknesses.

Also, each implementation of a language has strengths and weaknesses. [CPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) is not the same as [Jython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython) and [PyPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyPy) is different again.

Python is very good in the "business logic-to-lines of code" ratio: it has a pretty succinct way of putting things.

C++ is good at lower-level functionality, but given good code can also express high-level functionality with clean code.

Performance of well-written C++ code will *usually* be better than equivalent Python code, but performance is not always an important measurement of code.

When big-budget games use Python (or other dynamic languages), then they usually don't write their whole project in that language. Instead they use a base engine written in some lower-level language (C, C++) and implement some (or most or all) of the "business logic" in the dynamic language. That provides the best of both worlds.

Comment: The "well-written" part is key, though. Doing good data structures in C/C++ is a pain, so a lot of people don't bother. Python's data structures are going to be a lot faster than anything most people write themselves, and the use of better algorithms will often dwarf the micro-optimisations available in C/C++. Once you have a well-structured program, with good algorithmic choices, *then* you can look at finding the bottlenecks and optimising them (perhaps with Cython, perhaps by dropping down to a custom C/C++ extension).

Comment: @ncoghlan: true. Most languages allow you to write "bad" code. Some languages simply make it a bit easier/harder than others ;-)

Comment: Indeed. I sometimes rephrase TOOWTDI as "try to make 'doing the right thing' and 'following the path of least resistance' as close to being the same thing as possible". Tools that don't follow that guideline can be charitably described as "expert friendly" :P

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, it is.

But this heavily depends on your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Yes and Yes. Python is for Real Programmers.

Must Read http://www.paulgraham.com/pypar.html

Refer For More. http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageComparisons